# Why are there multiple version of Magic The Gathering Game on Steam?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm new to this famous card game. I searched it on steam and found multiple version e.g. 2012, 2015, etc
I'm planing on purchasing this online version of the game to see it but I got curious. Does the game has a new version as an entire new game every year? If so do I have to purchase the 2016 version next year to stay up to date?
Thanks

Comment: These versions mainly correlate with new Magic core releases in terms of introducing new cards, abilities and such (2014, 2015 etc). They have some difference in game modes, and have different funtionality. For example most players dislike new 2015 version and advise new buyers to buy 2014 instead. I personally own 2012 and 2014 versions and decided to skip 2015 due to negative reviews from players.

Comment: If you are planning to buy one, I would go with 2014 as it is better than 2015 in many aspects and it is cheaper to get, especially on sales.

Comment: yep, definitely buying 2014 now that I have read comment section in steam.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You appear to be talking about Duel of the Planeswalkers, a game *based on* M:TG where you start with a number of decks and you unlock cards to add to those as you progress in the game. There were different versions for the past few years. Each version had new decks and features. You can compare it to several sport games (NBA 2k15, WWE 2k15), they all get newer and sometimes better versions each year.

You can, however, keep using the older versions. But newer versions contain newer (and sometimes more) cards, new enemies, new battle types etc.

There is also Magic: Online, a true digital equivalent of Magic: The Gathering. This is a version which stays up to date with newer cards, but can be more expensive than the DotP versions you can buy (eg) in Steam. In MTGO, you create your own collection and play against other players, not against AI opponents.

Comment: As an additional detail, WotC updates the card sets and methods for building decks as well. I think the pattern is that each release covers about six blocks, always including the previous block and never including the one about to be released.

Comment: @jprete, No, that's not the case for DotP. The decks use cards from throughout history. And I thought MTGO gave you access to all cards?

Comment: There are some older sets that have never been released on MTGO. Only recently was the power nine available, but not via Alpha, rather through a special set called Vintage Masters. As per MTGSalv, "All cards from core sets after 7th Edition and expansions after Mirage are fully featured in Magic Online (This included cards in Reserved List, as the reprint policy does not apply in non-paper medium). For cards prior than that and some non-regular sets after Magic Online's launch (like Conspiracy), they are featured in Magic Online exclusive sets instead."

Comment: Sorry, I did not phrase the comment very well; I did not mean to include MTGO. My impression of DotP is that they usually picked cards from a number of specific blocks and themed all of the SP content around those blocks; I didn't mean that they only pick the most recent ones, merely that the very most recent block seems to always be included. I only have experience with two releases, however. Regarding MTGO, Wikipedia says that about 800 pre-Mirage cards haven't been released, so you are correct for most purposes.

Answer (score 5):

[Magic Duels](http://magic.wizards.com/en/content/magic-duels) is a free-to-play game that serves as an excellent tutorial and is now being updated with all new cards (but no old ones) rather than the yearly releases of the past.

WotC has now changed from a yearly release (DotP13, 14, 15, etc) to one release that will be supported going forward. This is called Magic Duels.

It came out with the Origins release, with the intention of providing running updates with each new set.

It is free to play; you buy booster packs with coins earned through victory, quests, or purchasing them for cash. Currently there is a starter pack provided when you download it that contains cards mainly from Origins, but there are also some cards from throughout Magic's history. There is also a Battle for Zendikar starter box, and likely to be a starter box for each large set.

Other than that, all cards in the app are from Origins and Battle for Zendikar. Oath of the Gatewatch was not able to be provided in time and is being added Wednesday, April 6, at the same time Shadows Over Innistrad is added to the app.

The game serves as an excellent tutorial as it explains each mechanic as you come across it through guided scenarios, but they are optional so if you already know what you're doing you can move on. The app also contains stories based on the [Magic Storyline](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/columns/magic-story-archive) that closely (though not precisely) follow the stories of each planeswalker for the Origins set, and an additional chapter for Battle for Zendikar.

Comment: Hi Robert, I was going to add a similar answer when I saw this, but as it would have looked very similar to yours, I hope it's okay that I did a bit of cleanup on yours instead. Let me know if you don't like any of the changes I've made, and feel free to rollback.

Comment: Magic duels has since been abandoned and now Magic the Gathering Arena was released as hopefully what duels was supposed to be (the final overarching release for all new sets)